# externaldocument references with standalone

Tags: cross-referencing, standalone, xr

I have a main document, /home/con/Documents/Thesis/thesis.tex, that loads a file /home/con/Documents/RNA/rna.tex with standalone.  This works surprisingly well.

However, there are 2 problems:
1. rna.tex has a supporting information file and numerous labels throughout which are referenced like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
....
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{/home/con/Documents/RNA/SI}
\begin{document}
...
\ref{tab:SI_table_X}
...
\end{document}
```

this works fine when rna.tex is by itself.  However, standalone package doesn't recognize externaldocument references in the thesis file, thesis.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
...
\usepackage{standalone,xr}
\externaldocument{/home/con/Documents/RNA/SI}%this line doesn't change anything
\begin{document}
...
\input{/home/con/Documents/RNA/rna.tex}%external references contained here
...
\end{document}
```

How can I get standalone to work with xr package to recognize references in SI files?

2. The page numbering restarts when rna.tex is referenced by the main document with the "\input{rna.tex}".

How can I make the page numbering stay the same as the main document? I've already used \pagestyle{empty} and \thispagestyle{empty} but they don't work with standalone.

The standalone documentation doesn't even reference \externaldocument :(

thanks so much,
-DEC